# Will I sued for recording someone without their consent?

Tags: evidence, recording, child-abuse, philippines

I want to know if I can be sued in the Philippines for recording someone without letting them know? I was being ganged up by my own family and decided to hide under my blanket when I decided to record them so that I have evidence that they are abusing me. It's not a video recording but an audio recording so they don't know that I was recording them.

Comment: You should be more concerned that it is a crime which can result in at least 6 months and up to 6 years imprisonment.

Answer (score 1):

It is illegal to record someone without their consent in the Philippines. 
https://www.lawphil.net/statutes/repacts/ra1965/ra_4200_1965.html

> Section 1. It shall be unlawful for any person, not being authorized by all the parties to any private communication or spoken word, to tap any wire or cable, or by using any other device or arrangement, to secretly overhear, intercept, or record such communication or spoken word by using a device commonly known as a dictaphone or dictagraph or dictaphone or walkie-talkie or tape recorder, or however otherwise described: